# Error : Detected background switch for net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(58) who has NO tunnels open - defocus NOT called

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

Im working in eclipse with bb plugin and the problem is when i click in my app then simulator freezes and I can not do anything. I tried to do something but its still the same

And Also I app have a background component (THREAD), here i leave the code when i call the method

app have a background component

public void callback(final ServiceResult result) {

```
    if(result.getException()!=null){
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("error:"+ result.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    this.section = (Vector) result.getData() ;
    // take first element of Result Object
    final Section section = (Section) this.section.elementAt(0);

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            pushScreen(new SubsectionScreen(section, 0));
        }
    });


}
```

and this is a part of the log

```
Starting faix
faix already running
Foreground faix(180)
Detected background switch for net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(58) who has NO tunnels open - defocus NOT called
Detected foreground switch for faix(180) who has NO tunnels open - focus NOT called
JVM: bklt @63289: timer
JVM: bklt[1] @63289: idle 2
JVM: bklt @63289: setTimer 13
VM:+GC(f)w=11
VM:-GCt=7,b=1,r=0,g=f,w=11
VM:QUOT t=1
VM:+CR
VM:-CR=2
JVM: bklt @76687: timer
JVM: bklt[1] @76687: idle 15
JVM: bklt @76687: setTimer 15
JPGENC 39 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 0 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 0 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 0 ms
JPGENC 0 ms
JPGENC 7 ms
JPGENC 0 ms
```

Please any advice. Thank you for take this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cleaning the simulator, on the new plugin that would be (inside eclipse):
Project > Blackberry > Clean Simulator,
Select all packages and click clean.

That helped me solve this problem.

Also, when you debug on the device, after a debug session, i have to uninstall the deployed app from the device manually (using the device) before initiating another debug session from eclipse... i know, its a pain but its the way it worked for me.

Cheers!